# Wordpress Twenty Eleven Template Page Issue

Tags: wordpress

I'm running into a curious problem with the Twenty Eleven theme.  I have copied the theme to my own folder (using it to create a new theme...I should have gone the child-theme route but...I didn't).  So far all is good.  Now I want to create a custom verson of the sidebar-page.php template.

1. I grab the template page that has a sidebar: sidebar-page.php
2. I make an exact copy, changing the name to sidebar-page2.php
3. I change the template name of the new file from "Sidebar Template" to "Sidebar Template2"
4. I upload (no changes to the structure of the template)
5. I change a page's template to "Sidebar Template2" from "Sidebar Template"

Load the page, it looks different.  It's almost as if the content is more centered, the H1 tag for the page is moved down, to the right and is bigger.

I can't find any info on this.  I found one post where someone had the same problem (on another site) but no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the answer on [another page](http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/twenty-eleven-new-page-template-with-sidebar-correction):

Basically, the problem is that it's adding another class to the body tag, in this case the 'singular' class. So here's something you can add to your functions.php file to filter that class for the sidebar-page2.php template file (or any other file, just replace sidebar-page2.php).

```
add_filter('body_class', 'adjust_body_class', 20, 2);
function adjust_body_class($wp_classes, $extra_classes) {

if( is_page_template('sidebar-page2.php') ) :
// Filter the body classes    

      foreach($wp_classes as $key => $value) {
      if ($value == 'singular') unset($wp_classes[$key]);
      }

endif;
// Add the extra classes back untouched
return array_merge($wp_classes, (array) $extra_classes );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have an unbalanced tag somewhere. Check to see that the  is where you expect it.  You may want to use Firebug or Chrome's Html viewer to verify the html is exactly the same.

Another possibility would be that the CSS is looking for a specific tag structure to which to apply styles. Again, Firebug or Chrome could help you locate this.

Without posted code, however, it would be difficult to answer it directly.

Comment: I've made no changes to the template other than changing the name.  Also no error when running through W3C validator

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem!

It seems that the css classes on the body tags are different. On the copied template, the page has singular class, while the actual sidebar-page template doesn't. Clearly, there must be some logic in the theme that checks if the sidebar-page template is being used or not and alters the css classes. Not sure where this logic is in the theme yet, though.

sidebar-page template:

```
<body class="page page-id-2 page-template page-template-sidebar-page-php logged-in admin-bar single-author two-column right-sidebar">
```

side-page-copy template:

```
<body class="page page-id-2 page-template page-template-sidebar-copy-page-php logged-in admin-bar single-author singular two-column right-sidebar">
```